# The data in a before hook does not contains the old record

Tags: feathersjs

I want to get all record before it is changed by patch, update, remove. If I try to do this in the before hook by get the record with the _id the record is allready changed.

Answer (score 0):

When executed properly, the data in a `before` hook will not be changed yet. The important thing is to wait for the call to return (e.g. using `async/await`) like this:

```
app.service('myservice').hooks({
  before: {
    async patch(context) {
      const entry = await context.service.get(context.id);

      console.log('Got old entry', entry);

      return context;
    }
  }
})
```